# MYSQL - Join three big tables

Tags: mysql, join, limit

I suppose to execute this query in MySQL:

```
SELECT `id`, `state`, `city`, `company`, `manager`, `district`, `group`, `subgroup` FROM `data_table` WHERE `id` IN ( 
SELECT DISTINCT `dataID` FROM `tags_data` WHERE `table` = 'data_table' AND `tagID` IN ( 
    SELECT `id` FROM `tags` WHERE `tag` LIKE '%fruit%' 
) LIMIT 0, 20 );
```

But MySQL 5.5 doesn't support `IN` and `LIMIT` commands together!

```
#1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'
```

so i have to use `INNER JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN` and merge these tables in order to use LIMIT

but my problem is these there table are BIG TABLES and this query may be used several times per every page! So cost of query's time is important for me!

I know this question may be repetitive but I have been confused.

Comment: I think you need to move LIMIT 0,20 inside like this ( 
    SELECT `id` FROM `tags` WHERE `tag` LIKE '%fruit%' LIMIT 0, 20 );

Comment: moving LIMIT to internal select change the results, because inner select just have one result.

Comment: The clue is in the question. The clue is "JOIN"

Comment: i know i must use JOIN but performance is matter!

Comment: A properly keyed JOIN is likely to be faster than sing IN with a sub query. However your current sql appears to be getting a random 2 rows (there is nothing to order the rows to specify which 20 are retrieved) from the tags_data table to check their dataID which seems strange

Answer (score 2):

You can get rid of your sub queries and use join subquery will run run for each row so it might cost you in place of them ,and then use proper indexes ,select only the columns you need

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT
  d.`id`,
  d.`state`,
  d.`city`,
  d.`company`,
  d.`manager`,
  d.`district`,
  d.`group`,
  d.`subgroup` 
FROM
  `data_table`  d
  JOIN `tags_data` td ON (d.id =td.dataID) 
  JOIN  `tags`  t ON (t.id =td.`tagID`)
  WHERE td.`table` = 'data_table' AND t.`tag` LIKE '%fruit%'
  LIMIT 0, 20
```

Indexes

```
ALTER TABLE `tags_data` ADD INDEX `indexname1` (`dataID`); 
ALTER TABLE `tags_data` ADD INDEX `indexname2` (`tagID`);
```

or you can join your tables with limit like so and also the where condition `WHERE td.`table`= 'data_table'` can be used in join query

```
JOIN 
(select dataID from `tags_data` WHERE `table` = 'data_table' limit 0,20)
 td ON (d.id =td.dataID)
```

Answer (score 1):

thanx to [M Khalid Junaid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/853360/m-khalid-junaid) , i used query like this:

```
SELECT dataTable.`id`, dataTable.`state`, dataTable.`city`, dataTable.`company`, dataTable.`manager`, dataTable.`district`, dataTable.`group`, dataTable.`subgroup`
    FROM `data_table` AS dataTable
    JOIN `tags_data`
    ON dataTable.`id`=`tags_data`.`dataID`
    JOIN `tags`
    ON `tags_data`.`tagID`=`tags`.`id`
    WHERE `tags`.`tag` LIKE '%friut%' AND `tags_data`.`table`='data_table'
    LIMIT 0, 20;
```

and the performance was acceptable.